# What does the Jormungand system even do?

Tags: jormungand

Maybe I was not paying attention in class, but it seems Jormungand is an autonomous AI system that destroys all aircraft indiscriminately once it has been activated. It indiscriminately robs everybody of air travel, even Koko. It would make sense if it could leave civilian planes alone or obey their operators.

With what weapons does Jormungand enforce "no air travel, ever"? Does it attack even low-altitude gliders? Is is completely indiscriminate, since it destroyed all aircraft at once? Can Koko override it?

Answer (score 1):

From the [Jormungand Wiki](http://jormungand.wikia.com/wiki/Jormungand_plan):

> Its purpose was to end war and arms trade by closing off the skies for all air travel. If humanity was not completely discouraged from war, Jormungand would be adapted to denying sea and land travel as well.
>
> How Jormungand could enforce aerial denial is unknown.

Comment: So is Koko directing it herself?

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood of the explanations in the anime and manga, I believe the AI would hack into the systems of the planes and control towers and either reroute them to collide with each other, or cause a malfunction in the plane systems themselves to make them literally drop out of the sky upon activation, and disallow any other planes to take off.